# Math.Log vs multiplication complexity in terms of geometric average which is better?

Tags: c#, mathematical-optimization, logarithm

I want to find geometric average of data and performance does matters.
Which one should I pick between

1. Keep multiplication over single variable and take Nth-root at the end of calculation

   ```
   X = MUL(x[i])^(1/N)
   ```

   Thus, `O(N) x Multiplication Complexity + O(1) x Nth-root`
2. Use logarithm

   ```
   X = e ^ { 1/N * SUM(log(x[i])) }
   ```

   Thus, `O(N) x Logarithm Complexity + O(1) x Nth-division + O(1) Exponential`
3. Specialized algorithm for geometric average. Please tell me if there is.

Comment: Bear in mind that you can more easily get overflows with the product method.

Comment: Comparing asymptotic complexity in this case is of no use because the constant factors dominate.

Comment: with logarithm case (number 2), the X on the left is actually the log of geometric average, so you also need to exponentiate at the end.

Comment: Nice catches @James, it was never hit overflow yet but perhaps I could truncate current multiplication using log into new variable `Y` and start `X` as new multiplication set. Then I will merge the result from `X` and `Y`

Comment: @usr I just want to approximate complexity in term of time on average case compare between Large number Multiplication or Many Small Logarithm.

Comment: Benchmark it. But as far as speed is concerned, usually the multiplication should be much faster, since a `log` is much more complicated than a multiplication. That can however change if the multiplication way produces subnormal numbers. And it can far easier overflow or lose precision/underflow to 0 than the `log` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I would try to benchmark this and get a comparison, here is my attempt.

Comparing was difficult since the list of numbers needed to be large enough to make timing it reasonable, so N is large. In my test N = 50,000,000 elements.

However, multiplying lots of numbers together which are greater than 1 overflows the double storing the product. But multiplying together numbers less than 1 gives a total product which is very small, and dividing by the number of elements gives zero.

Just a couple more things: Make sure none of your elements are zero, and the Log approach doesn't work for negative elements.

(The multiply would work without overflow if C# had a BigDecimal class with an Nth root function.)

Anyway, in my code each element is between 1 and 1.00001

On the other hand, the log approach had no problems with overflows, or underflows.

Here's the code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting...");
        Console.WriteLine("");

        Stopwatch watch1 = new Stopwatch();
        Stopwatch watch2 = new Stopwatch();

        List<double> list = getList();

        double prod = 1;

        double mean1 = -1;

        for (int c = 0; c < 2; c++)
        {
            watch1.Reset();

            watch1.Start();

            prod = 1;

            foreach (double d in list)
            {
                prod *= d;
            }

            mean1 = Math.Pow(prod, 1.0 / (double)list.Count);

            watch1.Stop();

        }

        double mean2 = -1;

        for (int c = 0; c < 2; c++)
        {
            watch2.Reset();

            watch2.Start();

            double sum = 0;

            foreach (double d in list)
            {
                double logged = Math.Log(d, 2);
                sum += logged;
            }

            sum *= 1.0 / (double)list.Count;

            mean2 = Math.Pow(2.0, sum);

            watch2.Stop();

        }
        Console.WriteLine("First way gave: " + mean1);
        Console.WriteLine("Other way gave: " + mean2);

        Console.WriteLine("First way took: " + watch1.ElapsedMilliseconds + " milliseconds.");
        Console.WriteLine("Other way took: " + watch2.ElapsedMilliseconds + " milliseconds.");

        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static List<double> getList()
    {
        List<double> result = new List<double>();

        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 50000000; i++)
        {
            result.Add( rand.NextDouble() / 100000.0 + 1);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

My computer output describes that both geometric means are the same, but that:

```
Multiply  way took: 466 milliseconds
Logarithm way took: 3245 milliseconds
```

So, the multiply appears to be faster.

But multiply is very problematic with overflow and underflow, so I would recommend the Log approach, unless you can guarantee the product won't overflow and that the product won't get too close to zero.

Comment: But does the multiple approach get a truly correct answer?  I don't think any finite-sized accumulator can retain the precision of multiplication over that sort of sample size.  (And it's not a very practical constraint on the values, the geometric mean presumably comes out to about 1.000005 or so just because of the narrow spread of the values, assuming a reasonably-uniform random distribution over that range.)  Instead of using such a large sample size, try a more sensible size and repeat the calculation in a loop many times (and/or use a StopWatch timer).

Comment: @RobParker This test was not meant to be the final say, I built something in 10 minutes that answered my question (I even warmed up the code before timing). But yes, it would be better to: a) time outside of a loop, and then b) divide by the num of iterations, and then c) subtract out the loop overhead, and d) do that several times keeping track of the min and average timings, then e) report that over a statistical distribution, f) restart the computer to test from an empty cache, g) etc. - Once you start timing, It's hard to know when to stop. :[

Comment: By adding an extra zero to the loop you see why the log is to prefer

Starting...

First way gave: INF
Other way gave: 1.00000500017156
First way took: 2490 milliseconds.
Other way took: 19285 milliseconds.

Press enter to exit